# cannot generate early bound types CRM 2013 online

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

In order to follow this tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695790.aspx) I need to generate some early bound types. I cannot get the tool to work.

- I've downloaded the latest CRM 2013 SDK
- I've got a CRM2013 online trial account.
- the URL I use is the one I got from the CRM2013->Settings->Customizations->Developer recources->organisation service.

the credential i use the default user (admin) from the CRM2013 online trial.
lets say it's John360

- So the URL for CRM is like https://john360.crm4.dynamics.com/
- user: john@john360.onmicrosoft.com
- pwd: pass
- organisationService: https://john360.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

when I try the command like:

```
 CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Xrm\Xrm.cs /url:https://john360.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /username:john /domain:john360.onmicrosoft.com /password:pass /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

i get

```
value cannot be null. Parameter name: identityProvider
```

I also tried some Obvious other with or without quotes, with the 'domain' appended to the username, nothing works. I added the program to the firewall.
I also tried this tool https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/
It also has problems connecting to the server. I tried with the latest version and with these connection settings: use CRM online and selected the crm4.dynamics.com
Login: john@john360.onmicrosoft.com, password: pass.
If I select 'Get Orgs.' I get the error

```
'an unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party'
```

I've now also tried this route: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SdkSoapjs-Entity-Class-14ca830f
The program gives the same error as the other generator.

edit:
I actually got a bit further... with this command:

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /out:Xrm.cs /url:"https://john360.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" /username:"john@john360.onmicrosoft.com" /password:"pass" /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext /serviceContextPrefix:
```

it resultet in error:

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved.
```

I didn't do any customization changes to my trail, so I'm not sure what this is about. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: did you try with an older sdk? try with 6.0.0 https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4B83260B94D4158!1387&authkey=!ALuzupR9uXK3iII&ithint=folder%2c.exe

Comment: don't know why, but with 6.0.0 it worked. (using the last command I mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com) as a method of connecting to CRM, I've created a GUI front end wrapper over the CrmSvcUtil.exe.  It adds a lot of additional features, but most importantly for you, it creates the commandline required to generate the entities for you.  Download it from the plugin store within the Xrm Tool Box, and never have this problem again!

Comment: I love this plugin and use it semi-daily!

Comment: Semi-daily?  Someone needs to lay off the juice!